# Windows Server 2008 delayed start services

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am noticing on my new 2008 server that the Automatic(delayed Start ) services arent starting at all, even the default wndows ones, any ideas?

Comment: That is strange. Have you checked your event log? If not, search for any events that may correlate to your services.

Comment: looks asif one of the automatic services is failing, woud cause all delayed seice to not start?

Comment: if so, that is a lil scary

Comment: well i set the servicethat was failing to manual and the delayed services started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer seems to be if you have any services that ae set to auto and they fail that all services that are delayed will not start.  IMO, that is a really bad idea and not really sure if that was the intended behaviour by MS, if nyone has any ideas on this or comments I wouldlove to hear them

Comment: You need to check the service dependencies.  Did any other the other services that didn't start have this specific service as a dependency?

Comment: the service that failed was one of my on custom services, which was why i was experimenting ith delayed start in the first place sice it had a binding to sockets issue, so rather than build a list of dependencies i decided t make it a delayed start, when it failed I saw other delayed service not start